# Angular Service Injection Issue: @Injectable Doesn't Work but Providers Does

Tags: angular, angular6

I scanned through SO but couldn't find anything with my seemingly weird issue. I'll begin by copying in some of my code to give context:

My Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { MyModule } from './my.module';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: MyModule,
})
export class ApiService {

  // router: Router;

  constructor() {
    // this.router = MyModule.injector.get(Router);
  }
... Some methods ...
}
```

My Module:

```
import { NgModule, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ConnectionsListComponent } from './connections-list/connections-list.component';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import * as fromMy from './reducers';
import { routes } from './routes';
... component imports ...

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    StoreModule.forFeature('my', fromMy.reducers),
  ],
  declarations: [ConnectionsListComponent, MyShellComponentComponent, DashboardContainerComponent, DashboardElementComponent, DashboardElementInfoItemComponent],
  // providers: [ApiService]
})
export class MyModule {

  constructor() {

  }
}
```

My Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { AttributeArrayHelperService } from '../attribute-array-helper.service';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service';

.. some interfaces ...

@Component({
  selector: 'vz-dashboard-element',
  templateUrl: './dashboard-element.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard-element.component.scss']
})
export class DashboardElementComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() element: ElementInterface;
  @Input() erpType: String;

  equipmentAttributes: Object[] = []

  workOrderAttributes: Object[] = [

  ];

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {

   }

  ngOnInit() {
    const helper = new AttributeArrayHelperService();
    console.log(this.element);
    const lookupValues = helper.parseObjectArrayFor(this.element.Attributes, ['1', '2', '3']);
    console.log(lookupValues);
    const showValues = helper.parseArrayNames(lookupValues);
    console.log(showValues);
    console.log(this.apiService);
    console.log(this.apiService.getDashboardEntityInformation('4', '5', '6'));
    showValues.push();
    this.equipmentAttributes = showValues;
  }
}
```

OK, so now that that's there here is my issue: When I am trying to use the @Injectable as I have it above, with the module declared, I get the following error in my browser but no TS compilation error (there is a circular ref warning though):

> DashboardContainerComponent.html:2 ERROR Error:
>   StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[DashboardElementComponent ->
>   ApiService]:    StaticInjectorError(Platform:
>   core)[DashboardElementComponent -> ApiService]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for ApiService!

When I change it to use @Injectable() and uncomment my providers it seems to like it and everything is fine. I'm just curious as to why this is? From reading the Angular documentation for 6.1 this seems to fit what is needed.

For further information this is all inside a submodule and the service is meant to be isolated to this module. At this point, I'm just perplexed as to what I'm missing and as one of few JS people in my office, and the only using Angular, I don't have a second set of eyes to help me identify what I'm missing.

Any help in doing so is GREATLY appreciated as this has been eating at me for a few days now. Thanks in advance,

Steve

Edit: Another thing to note is this was an app that was upgraded from 5 to 6. I followed the guide and got it all working, so maybe it sources from the upgrade?

Comment: Have you tried restarting the app, that is restarting `ng serve`?

Comment: @AlfMoh yes, I've done it multiple times as well as hard refreshing the browser after each restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after researching this issue and functionality further, I have found I'm not the only one with this issue and it seems to come from a misunderstanding of the documentation. As referenced here: [GitHub Angular CLI Issue 10170](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10170) the way I was going about this is wrong, though the documentation on the feature would seem to tell you otherwise.

Essentially, it is creating an import loop and TS is doing its job in preventing such an issue. The now recommended way to use `@Injectable()` is with `{ providedIn: 'root' }` which makes the injectable service available at the root level of the application. That being said, it does appear to only be bundled at the top level if it is used in multiple modules or the root module. If the service is only used in a single sub-module it is bundled with that submodule.

My solution was to change to

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
```

for my new services, and the rest I have left as in the `providers` array of the module definition of their respective modules. At least until `providers` is no longer supported this will all work well together, at that time I will convert them all to this new format.